# When is $\mathrm{Gal}(X^4 + pX + p / \mathbb{Q}) \subsetneq S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, galois-theory

I'm looking for a solution verification. I'm getting to grips with Galois theory and this question seems to require various results to be stringed together, so I hope I've gotten it all correct. This question was part of an examination question in a past year.

> Let $p$ be a prime. When is $\mathrm{Gal}(X^4 + pX + p / \mathbb{Q}) \subsetneq S_4$?

---

**My solution**

Firstly, note $f(X) = X^4 + pX + p$ has resolvent cubic $g(X) = X^3-4pX-p^2$.

$g$ is irreducible: Suppose it were reducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. It is a cubic and thus has an integer root $x$. Taking $x^3 - 4px - p^2 \mod p$ shows $x = np$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Substitue this back in to get $n^3 p - 4n - 1 = 0$. By taking this equation mod $|n|$ we see $n = \pm 1$, but verify neither $\pm p$ solve $g$. Hence $g$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, and thus also $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ (Gauss' lemma).

As $g$ is an irreducible cubic, it's Galois group is either $S_3$ or $A_3$.

There is a result stating that the Galois group of a polynomial is contained in the alternating group precisely when its discriminant is a square.

The discriminant of $g$ is $-4(-4p)^3 - 27(-p^2)^2 = 256p^3 - 27p^4$.

$256p^3 - 27p^4$ is a perfect square if and only if $256p - 27p^2$ is a perfect square. In particular we need $p \mid 256 - 27p$. So $p \mid 256$. So $p = 2$. But we can check that $256 \cdot 2^3 - 27 \cdot 2^4 = 1616$, and $1616$ is not a square number. So no such polynomials have such a Galois group.

---

Is this correct? Are there any other ways to see this that may give more intuition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we are given an irreducible quartic $f\in\mathbb Q[X]$, with auxilliary cubic $g$, and discriminant $\Delta$. The general theory then tells us that, if $g$ is itself irreducible, then $\mathrm{Gal}(f)=A_4$ if $\Delta$ is a rational square, and $\mathrm{Gal}(f)=S_4$ otherwise.

In our situation, where $f=X^4+pX+p$ for a prime $p$, we know that the discriminant is $\Delta=p^3(256-27p)$, which is never a rational square (as you showed).

Also, $g=X^3-4pX-p^2$, and any rational solution is of the form $pa$, where $pa^3-4a-1=0$ (again as you showed). This gives $a(pa^2-4)=1$, so either $a=1$ and $p=5$, or $a=-1$ and $p=3$.

Thus for $p\neq3,5$ we have that $g$ is irreducible, and hence that $\mathrm{Gal}(f)=S_4$.

If $p=3$, then $g=(X+3)(X^2-3X-3)$, whereas if $p=5$, then $g=(X-5)(X^2+5X+5)$. This is where your argument was wrong.

If $g$ factors as a linear and an irreducible quadratic, then the general theory tells us that $\mathrm{Gal}(f)$ is either $C_4$ (cyclic of order 4) or $D_4$ (dihedral of order 8).

When $p=3$, we can use that $f=(X-1)^2(X^2+2X+3)$ modulo $7$ to see that the Galois group contains an element of cycle type $1,1,2$, so a transposition. Thus $\mathrm{Gal}(f)=D_4$.

When $p=5$ I think the Galois group is $C_4$.

Comment: IIRC, you can't rely on factorizations over primes that divide the discriminant ($7$ in this case). But $$ x^4+3x+3=(x+2)(x+4)(x^2+7x+2)\pmod{13}$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, we should avoid repeated roots.